# How to make a simple Twitter clone app with parse?

Tags: java, android, twitter, parse-server

I'm making a twitter clone in android studio using parse server, I want to store the tweets and comments in parse account. I can store Tweets but I don't know how to store comments of that particular tweet in my parse account. I want to arrange all tweets and their comments in the expandable listview of my app.
Can I store hashmaps in parse server using tweet as a key and comments as a value?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new class in your app called `Comment`, which should have a `Pointer` to the `Tweet` class. Then you can save a new `Comment` object with a code like the below:

```
// Create the comment
ParseObject comment = new ParseObject("Comment");
comment.put("content", "Some comment.");

// Add a relation between the Tweet and Comment
comment.put("tweet", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Tweet", "1zEcyElZ80")); // This is the tweet id to which the comment belongs

// This will save both myPost and myComment
comment.saveInBackground();
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-data

Comment: So when I comment on other's tweet, I need to first find that tweet in my Tweet class using Parsequery and then make a relation between that tweet with my comment

Comment: If you already have the Tweet id, you don't need to use parse query to find the whole object. You can just pass the id as in my example above. But, if for any reason you already had to use parse query to find the tweet object, you can also pass it directly like this: `comment.put("tweet", tweet);`